# why is grails not populating data via bootstrap

Tags: grails, grails-orm, bootstrapping

I have the following bootstrap class

```
import shoppingsolutionproject.Category;
import shoppingsolutionproject.Item

class BootStrap {

    def dataSource

    def init = { servletContext ->
        new Category(description: 'Car').save()
        new Category(description: 'Truck').save()
        new Item(productNumber:1, name:"First Product", description: "This is the first product I'm adding for testing",
                 shippingCost: 4.99, url: '/first', retailPrice: 19.99, salePrice: 16.99, category: 'Car').save()
        new Item(productNumber:2, name:"Second Product", description: "This is the second product I'm adding for testing",
                shippingCost: 4.99, url: '/second', retailPrice: 19.99, category: 'Truck').save()
        new Item(productNumber:3, name:"First/Second Product", description: "This is the first/second(so third) product I'm adding for testing",
                shippingCost: 4.99, url: '/second', retailPrice: 17.99, category: 'Truck').save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

when I startup grails though, I don't have the categories or Items pre-populated...  any idea why?

Comment: Most likely you have validation errors. The quickest way to verify this is to add `failOnError: true` to your `.save()` like this: `.save(failOnError: true)`. That should show you lots of things that are failing due to validation errors.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore You are correct, I was using the string 'Car' as the category instead of Category object I created

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have validation errors.

The quickest way to verify this is to add `failOnError: true` to your `.save()` like this: `.save(failOnError: true)`.

That should show you lots of things that are failing due to validation errors.